# audio.js looping in ie9

Tags: javascript, audio

hello i have a problem with ie9 
i'm using plugin audio.js http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/ , and audio continues to loop in browser , i'm loading audio :

```
function play_voice_pre(vfile){
    var a = audiojs.createAll();
    a[0].load("assets/sound/wu/" + vfile);
    return a;
}

audio3 = play_voice_pre(path+"Program7-1-w-4.mp3");
```

and then start to play with

```
audio3[0].play()
```

i'm using more then one audio per page , and all audio starts to loop to infinite  ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's ok , i finded the solution

```
a[0].trackEnded=function() {
     a.pause();
}
```

track stops in ie9